# Access a Set that is modified by other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

There is an `ExecutorService` that has 3 threads that each one add `Pair<String,Integer>` objects to a `TreeSet<Pair<String,Integer>>`. The addToSet() method is declared `synchronized` and everything works fine. But I must implement a new thread that execute a scheduled task that has to access this Set and print all the values. The problem is that sometimes the scheduled thread crashes(the other threads work fine). I think that it crashes because the Set is being modified by the other 3 threads during the for loop of the printer(scheduled thread).

Comment: Do you get a `ConcurrentModificationException`?  Some code would help.

Comment: No. Only the printer just stops. The other threads continue to update the TreeSet

Comment: probably your `run` method is throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` that you are not handling.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://javaconcurrencyinpractice.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mutual exclusion between the `addToSet` method and the method which prints all values. One way to do that:

```
Object setLock = new Object(); // Put this in a scope where all threads can access it

void addToSet( T element ){
    synchronized(setLock) {
       //add it
   }
}

void printAllValues(){
   synchronized(setLock) {
       //print the values
   }
}
```

Comment: each Thread implements a Runnable class. How can I have access to the setLock object in two different classes? The method that calls these runnables in the same class. Should I have to pass it as an arg in the constructor of each runnable?

Comment: In that case, I think you should use the TreeSet object itself as a lock, since both classes have access to it. Just use it instead of `setLock`.

Comment: Works . Set the TreeSet object as a lock +1

Comment: Note that while this solution "works", it locks the shared data structure for all the time that the print process takes. During that time, no thread will be able to add any data to it. That's ok for  small sets of data but will create contention in the system as the data grows.

Comment: That's very true. If that's an issue, you should make a copy as in @maasg's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to implement this would be to create a defensive copy of the set in a synchronized context and use that for the other process.

In few rough lines:

```
public void run() {
    TreeSet<...> localSet;
    synchronized (commonSet ) {
        localSet = new TreeSet(commonSet);
    }
    doStuff(localSet);
    ...
}
```

Note that this does not solve concurrent access to objects in the set (if those are mutable.)